# Getting locator of web element on which action is performed

Tags: javascript, java, dom, web, html

Is it possible to get locator in terms of id/class/name etc of a webpage element on which actions like click or key event is performed. Is there any existing API in Java which I can use for this, if not then which technologies should I be using to fulfill such requirement?